# Can I include compile time resources (e.g. script files) in a Cocoapod?

Tags: cocoapods

I have a script/tool that I would like to include in my cocoapod to be used as a code generator utility. I'd just like it to be available to the user in the distribution as something like:
`Pods/MyPod/my_script.sh` for command line use or  integration into pre-compile phase hook.  Obviously this should not be deployed with the compiled application, it would only be of use at build time.

If I include the file in the Assets dir:
`s.resources = 'MyPod/Assets/**/*'`
then it will end up deployed in the framework with the application (right?).

Alternately I can include it in the `Classes` folder and I think that does what I want because it is ignored, but it feels like a hack.

Furthermore neither of the above solutions is helpful when referencing the pod during development time (e.g. with a `:path = ../`) because when in that mode the `Classes` and `Assets` folder don't seem to be copied or linked into the local Pods folder at all.  This makes it somewhat harder to test.

Is there any sanctioned way to include arbitrary files in a Cocoapod distribution?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I ended up creating a homebrew install for my utility, which made more sense for the command line tools and turned out to be very easy.  I was pleased to learn that creating a brew "formula" could be done in my own github repo without even publishing to the main "tap" (central server) if desired and that even under those circumstances installation was still a one-liner for the user.  As an example this is my project's brew repo: https://github.com/presentco/homebrew-utils